# How to handle the NextResponse in NextJS 13.4

Tags: reactjs, json, http-headers, next.js13

How can I receive the content of my request? Let's say we have a brand new app in NextJS 13.4 and in the app/api/route.tsx we have this

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
 
export async function GET() {
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
  const data = await res.json()
 
  return NextResponse.json({ data })

}
```

I want to know two things: why to use `NextResponse` and how.

The documentation don't show us how to handle the values in the page.js/ts

so here in the app/page.tsx I have this

```js
import Image from 'next/image'
import { GET } from '../api/route'

export default async function Home() {
    const data  = await GET()
    console.log(data)
    return(
        <>
            <div>Contents</div>
            <div>Goes Here</div>
        </>
    )
}
```

What is the right way to handle this? Because this is returning a bunch of header things and I couldn't find the content. If I remove this `NextResponse.json({ data })` and return only the `data` I'm able to get the values like this

```json
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

So can anyone explain me why the documentation tell me to use the `NextResponse` but don't explain how can I get the value in the actual front end.

It is right the way I'm importing and trying to receive the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> pages/api/route.ts

- Request is the standard [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) that you use in the browser and in
  recent versions of Node.js
- NextRequest is a subclass of Request that adds [several properties and methods](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/next-server#nextrequest). It's used in middleware
- NextApiRequest extends Node.js' IncomingMessage (from node:http) and also adds several helpers to it. It's used in API routes

  ```
     import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
     import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

    export async function handle(req: NextApiRequest, resp: NextApiResponse) {
     if (req.method === 'GET') {
         const res = await fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {
             headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             },
         })
         const data = await res.json()

         return resp.status(201).json(data);
     }
   }
  export default handle
  ```

> pages/app/index.tsx

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
const Page = (props) => {
const [state,setState]= useState([])
const getData = async () => {
const res = await fetch(`/api/route`
  , {
    method: "GET",
  },
)
const pos = await res.json()
 setState(pos)

}
useEffect(() => {
getData()
}, [])

console.log(state);

 return (
   <>
    <div >
   {state.map((item) => (
 <>
<p>{item.id}</p>
<p>{item.title}</p>
</>))}
 </div>
 </>
)}
export default Page
```